# Current conversations logic for simple messaging system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am building a simple messaging system with Rails3 that allows users to send private messages to each other. Each set of users can have a single stream of messages between each other (like texting)

I am confused however on the logic that is used to build the view that shows all current conversations going on for a user. This includes conversations that might only include sent messages from myself.

My schema has the following:

```
  create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "from_id"
    t.integer  "to_id"
    t.string   "message"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I would like to emulate something similar to FB messaging that shows a row for each conversation.`

Any ideas would be super helpful.

Thanks!
Danny

Comment: could you have a jquery-ui tab bar like [this one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#bottom) combined with [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation). Then you could use [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) like [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) to do the messaging. In the javascipt you could get the incoming message to start up a new tab with a new conversation.

Comment: I was looking for help with the sql/rails finder to help achieve this, but thanks!

Comment: I don't really see a question here, just a request for design ideas. Anyway, you might want to add a thread id to your model, since two people can be carrying on two different conversations simultaneously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two sets of messages to consider:

- Those where `from_id` is the current user.
- Those where `to_id` is the current user.

I'd go with a [`find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql) and let the database do all the work:

```
chatting_with = User.find_by_sql(%Q{
    select * from users where id in (
        select to_id   as user_id from messages where from_id = :the_user
        union all
        select from_id as user_id from messages where to_id   = :the_user
    )
}, :the_user => the_user_in_question.id)
```

An SQL UNION simply does a set-wise union of the two result sets so the above will grab all the users that `the_user_in_question` has sent messages to and combine that with the users that have sent messages to `the_user_in_question`; the result will be all the users that are involved in conversations with `the_user_in_question` as an array of User instances. Since there is an `IN` on the UNION you can use UNION ALL to avoid a little bit of extra work in the UNION.

You'd probably want to wrap that in a class method on Message:

```
def self.conversations_involving(user)
    User.find_by_sql(%Q{
        select * from users where id in (
            select to_id   as user_id from messages where from_id = :the_user
            union all
            select from_id as user_id from messages where to_id   = :the_user
        )
    }, :the_user => user.id)
end
```

And then you could just say things like:

```
@other_users = Message.conversations_involving(current_user)
```

in your controller.

You'll want to add indexes to `messages.from_id` and `messages.to_id` in your database too.